# UnboundLocalError when calling nragms method in Pattern python library

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, pyspark, runtime-error

I'm new to python and pyspark. I'm working with a code that runs on pyspark that builds a tfidfs model. However when calling the ngrams method of the famous Pattern library an UnboundLocalError is triggered.

This the `text` data layout it's `(id ,list[text])` extracted by `text.map(lambda x: (x["_id"], (x["span"], x["text"]))).groupByKey().map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1]))`:

```
[(u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodville_South,_South_Australia',
  [u'Campbell was born in Myrtle Bank.']),
 (u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picket_(military)',
  [u'The film dealt with the story .',
   u"Members of the Union force."]),
 (u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/320th_Troop_Carrier_Squadron',
  [u" The 1st Air Transport."])]
```

This is how the idfs are formatted:

```
Out[23]:                                                                        
[{'_id': u'1,800', 'idf': 7.245417283738939},
 {'_id': u'Poetry', 'idf': 5.399590593240608},
 {'_id': u'Bloodworth', 'idf': 7.938564464298884},
 {'_id': u'Mullally', 'idf': 7.938564464298884}]
```

Here is part of the code I'm working with:

```
corpus = text\
            .mapValues(lambda v: ngrams(v, self.max_ngram))\  """the ngrams method call """
            .flatMap(lambda (target, tokens): (((target, t), 1) for t in tokens))\
            .reduceByKey(add)\
            .map(lambda ((target, token), count): (token, (target, count)))\
```

This is the Pattern library method in `text.py`:

```
def ngrams(string, n=3, punctuation=PUNCTUATION, continuous=False):
    """ Returns a list of n-grams (tuples of n successive words) from the given string.
        Alternatively, you can supply a Text or Sentence object.
        With continuous=False, n-grams will not run over sentence markers (i.e., .!?).
        Punctuation marks are stripped from words.
    """
    def strip_punctuation(s, punctuation=set(punctuation)):
        return [w for w in s if (isinstance(w, Word) and w.string or w) not in punctuation]
    if n <= 0:
        return []
    if isinstance(string, basestring):
        s = [strip_punctuation(s.split(" ")) for s in tokenize(string)]
    if isinstance(string, Sentence):
        s = [strip_punctuation(string)]
    if isinstance(string, Text):
        s = [strip_punctuation(s) for s in string]
    if continuous:
        s = [sum(s, [])]
    g = []
    for s in s:         """ ERROR triggered here """
        #s = [None] + s + [None]
        g.extend([tuple(s[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(s)-n+1)])
    return g
```

This is the trace of the error message:

```
python2.7/site-packages/sift/util.py", line 8, in ngrams
    for n in en.ngrams(text, n=i+1, **pattern_args):
python2.7/site-packages/pattern/text/__init__.py", line 83, in ngrams
    for s in s:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
```

I know what the error means I tried editing the library method however the error remains, so maybe I didnt quite correct it or it's somewhere else. How can I resolve this error?

I'm using python 2.7 and pyspark 2.3.0.

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Comment: Apparently `v` has to be a string, Sentence, or Text, and it's none of those. Use a debugger or print to find out what `v` is.

Comment: @AlexHall To the best of my knowledge it's a string. Question is edited to show the processed data format.

Comment: Looks like `[u'The film dealt with the story .',
   u"Members of the Union force."]` is a possible value of `v`, which is definitely a list of strings, not a string.

Comment: @AlexHall how can I remove the list for the ngrams methodand maintain the grouping? Any idea in mind or suggestion will much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember your last question correctly, "v" is a result of groupByKey.
So the easiest way to make this work will probably be to make "v" into a string:

```
from pattern.en import ngrams

rdd = sc.parallelize([{'_id': u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerambycidae',
  'source': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plinthocoelium_virens',
  'span': (61, 73),
  'text': u'"Plinthocoelium virens" is a species of beetle in the family Cerambycidae.'},
 {'_id': u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dru_Drury',
  'source': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plinthocoelium_virens',
  'span': (20, 29),
  'text': u'It was described by Dru Drury in 1770.'},
 {'_id': u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dru_Drury',
  'source': 'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plinthocoelium_virens2',
  'span': (20, 29, 2),
  'text': u'It was described by Dru Drury in 1770.2'}])

print rdd.map(lambda x: (x["_id"], x["text"])).groupByKey()\
.map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1])))\
.mapValues(lambda v: ngrams(" ".join(v), 5))\
.collect()
```

> [(u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dru_Drury', [(u'It', u'was', u'described',
>   u'by', u'Dru'), (u'was', u'described', u'by', u'Dru', u'Drury'),
>   (u'described', u'by', u'Dru', u'Drury', u'in'), (u'by', u'Dru',
>   u'Drury', u'in', u'1770'), (u'It', u'was', u'described', u'by',
>   u'Dru'), (u'was', u'described', u'by', u'Dru', u'Drury'),
>   (u'described', u'by', u'Dru', u'Drury', u'in'), (u'by', u'Dru',
>   u'Drury', u'in', u'1770.2')]), (u'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerambycidae',
>   [(u'Plinthocoelium', u'virens', u'is', u'a', u'species'), (u'virens',
>   u'is', u'a', u'species', u'of'), (u'is', u'a', u'species', u'of',
>   u'beetle'), (u'a', u'species', u'of', u'beetle', u'in'), (u'species',
>   u'of', u'beetle', u'in', u'the'), (u'of', u'beetle', u'in', u'the',
>   u'family'), (u'beetle', u'in', u'the', u'family', u'Cerambycidae')])]

Comment: Thank you for the continuous support. I added the format of the data.

Comment: did exactly what you suggested and it caused ` map_values_fn = lambda kv: (kv[0], f(kv[1]))
KeyError: 0` error.

Comment: Did you remember to get rid of the "span"?

Comment: I installed "pattern" and the code above workes for me

Comment: Unfortunately it raised the keyerror again. I added the new error and traceback to the question.

Comment: Oh yes I know now where the error `map_values_fn = lambda kv: (kv[0], f(kv[1]))
KeyError: 0 ` occurs!! it's triggered in this line `.leftOuterJoin(idfs)\`. I added the format of idfs :)

Comment: Thank you your solution worked smoothly. The other error was due to other simple formatting issue. Thank you again.

Comment: You needed to change the flatMap to : .flatMap(lambda (target, token_lists): (((target, t), 1) for tokens in token_lists for t in tokens) )\

Comment: And change the join to: .leftOuterJoin(idfs.map(lambda x: (x["_id"], x["idf"])))\

Comment: And use "idf is not None" not "idf != None"

Comment: I tried it it caused another typeerror.  I only formatted the idfs as Out[14]: [(u'1,800', 7.245417283738939)] and your solution works smoothly :) Thank you again, hope this thread is useful for others too.

Answer (score 0):

In `if continuous:`, you're refering to `s`. But if no previous conditions were verified, `s` dosn't exist.

A simple fix would be to give an initial value to `s` before the ifs, like `[]`.

Also, you could rename this variable to avoid conflicts with loop variables.